# Kivy ScrollView won't scroll to lower content

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

I have a ScrollView that I am populating with AsyncImage objects. However, my ScrollView seems to think that there is nothing to scroll down to, and treats it like over scroll. I think this is because I am adding to its child layout after it is instantiated, but don't know how to fix it.

Faulty behavior: https://i.imgur.com/OjcR2RY.mp4

Now, I've thought about disabling overscroll behavior alltogether, but I need it to work correctly for a future feature.

main.py

```
import gc

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class ProviderWindow(Widget):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ProviderWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.C_L = GridLayout(cols=3, spacing=0, size_hint=(1, None), pos=(0, 0))
    
    def search(self):

        # Clear any existing images inside the view when starting a fresh search
        for child in App.get_running_app().root.ids.image_scroll_view.children:
            del child
        App.get_running_app().root.ids.image_scroll_view.clear_widgets()
        gc.collect(generation=2)

        # GridView properties
        self.C_L.col_default_width = 500
        self.C_L.row_default_height = 500

        urls = self.gb.search()  # Get a list of URLs to load into AsyncImages (can simply be a list of Strings)

        # Adding All images to GridLayout
        for entry in urls:
            img = AsyncImage(source=entry, keep_ratio=True, allow_stretch=True)
            img.size_hint = (1, 1)
            self.C_L.add_widget(img)

        # Adding GridLayout to ScrollView
        self.ids.image_scroll_view.add_widget(self.C_L)


class SimpleApp(App):
    pass
```

Simple.kv

```
ProviderWindow:

<ProviderWindow>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size_hint: None, None
        size: (root.size[0], root.size[1])

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            size_hint: 1, 0.1

            Button:
                id:search_button
                text:"Search"
                on_press: root.search()
                size_hint: 0.3,None

            TextInput
                id:tags
                size_hint: 0.4, None

            Button:
                id:search_button
                text:"More"
                size_hint: 0.3,None

            Button:
                id:settings_button
                text:"Settings"
                size_hint: 0.2, None


        ScrollView:
            id: image_scroll_view
            do_scroll_x: False
            do_scroll_y: True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to set the height to scale with the contents of the GridLayout.

I achieved this by adding

`self.C_L.bind(minimum_height=self.C_L.setter('height'))`

Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

when you use `GridLayout` or `BoxLayout`  you should specify there height otherwise they just will take there parent size

but when we use it inside `ScrollView` widget you should make the height equal to the `GridLayout` children using `minimum_height`

in you case the solution is

```py
self.C_L = GridLayout(cols=3, spacing=0, size_hint=(1, None), pos=(0, 0),height=self.minimum_height)
```

Comment: Doing so results in `AttributeError: 'ProviderWindow' object has no attribute 'minimum_height'`